# Serve Firebase Functions on Cloud9

Tags: google-cloud-functions, cloud9, firebase-cli

I'm trying to serve firebase functions for testing in cloud9. I'm doing the following:

```
$ firebase serve --only functions -o $IP -p $PORT

=== Serving from '/home/ubuntu/workspace'...

i  functions: Preparing to emulate functions.
✔  functions: myFunction: http://localhost:8080/myapp/us-central1/myFunction
```

This seems to work, but going to

```
http://myC9App-nicholasstephan.c9users.io:8080/myFirebaseApp/us-central1/myFunction
```

Gives me the c9 "No application seems to be running here!" screen.

What gives? Is there any way to test firebase functions through the emulator in c9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Step 1

  $ firebase serve -o 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
- Step 2:

  Go to ec2 security groups and add a custom TCP rule through port 8000
- Step 3:

  Copy your public ip and on your browser, type 
  (your ip):8000, e.g. 54.21.213.7:8000

Comment: This answer should be accepted has i have been looking all day for that and it just work! Thanks ...